# Can I restrict which Controllers are used in a Directive?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Is there a way I can limit which controllers are passed into a custom directive? i.e. only controllers that have the data/methods that are used in the template are valid options for the directive. Otherwise an error or warning of some kind is thrown. Is this even possible?

I'm using Angular 1.x.

Comment: How exactly do you want to *pass* a controller to the directive? Do you really want to pass a hole controller or do you want do pass some data of the parent controller to the directive?

Comment: You can specify a controller for a directive directly in the custom directive. Or you can append the directive to the controller directly. Or you can consider the `link` property as acting as a wrapper for any `scope` elements or functions. Please look here: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive